# AWS API Gateway Access-Control-Allow-Origin not being sent back

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway setup with a Lambda function (via the Lambda proxy setting). When I enable CORS on the gateway, I don't actually receive the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in my the response header. How do I send back this header?

I tried enabling CORS for each method and configuring the accepted origins as "*" but the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header does not show up in the response header, like I was expecting it to.

Answer (score 0):

Your backend is responsible for returning the Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Headers headers, because a proxy integration doesn't return an integration response.

Something like this.

```
    export const handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.example.com",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```